# How can I translate a typed query into a criteria builder object?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have the following code using `TypedQuery`, but due to some lack of dynamic functionality with `ORDER BY`, I would like to transform it into a criteria builder object. Is it possible to achieve the same query with the criteria builder?

```
TypedQuery<User> query = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN sales s ON u.id = s.user_id AND u.username LIKE :username", User.class);

query.setParameter("username", "%" + sampleUsername.toLowerCase() + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Every JPQL query can be implemented with Criteria API

Comment: Is it also possible without changing Entities? Or do they need to reflect `@ManyToOne` etc. ? How could it work for the above query?

Comment: Yes. A good start is the Java EE tutorial https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-criteria.html#GJITV